# Check if list contains a pair which adds up to a given sum

Tags: array, recursion, interview-questions, scala, k-sum

Kindly review this scala code for given problem and suggest improvements.

**Problem** - Given an array of integers and a target sum, check if array contains a pair which adds up to sum.

**Example** -

```
i/p - (1,2,4,5,6) 7 
o/p - true 

i/p - (1,1,1,5,6) 2
o/p - true

i/p - (1,4,4,5,6) 13
o/p - false
```

**Scala implementation**

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

object FindMatchingSum {
  def containsMatchingSum(data: Array[Int], complementTable: Set[Int], sum: Int): Boolean = {
    if (data.isEmpty) false
    else if (complementTable contains data.head) true
    else containsMatchingSum(data.drop(1), complementTable ++ Set(sum-data.head), sum)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {
    println(containsMatchingSum(Array(1,2,4,5,6), Set[Int](), 7))
    println(containsMatchingSum(Array(1,1,1,5,6), Set[Int](), 2))
    println(containsMatchingSum(Array(1,4,4,5,6), Set[Int](), 9))
    println(containsMatchingSum(Array(1,4,4,5,6), Set[Int](), 13))
  }
}
```

**Sample run**

```
scalac FindMatchingSum.scala                                                 
scala FindMatchingSum                                                        
true
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about efficiency you could copy the Array into a Vector or use an index instead of paring down the input.